# Python Pip Install: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, pip

I am using Anaconda Spyder and whenever I need to install a new package I just type pip install and then the name of the package in the console. However, when I tried installing a new package today I receive the error:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I don't believe I've changed any of my settings. The directory is the same directory I always use. I also tried in Jupyter notebooks and receive the same error. Tried googling the error and while I see it is a common error, nobody seems to be getting it while trying to pip install.

Not sure where to begin researching this error, does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OS are you trying on but could be issue with your PATH settings. Pls ensure you have valid directory path for your python directory. Can you pls provide more info about pip version and python version you are using

Comment: I'm using windows, Python version 3.8.8, pip 21.1.3

Comment: Can you check PATH variable in your environment variable

Comment: I tried googling how to do this, but didn't follow. Is this something I can do in Python?